# Why viewpager shows null pointer exception when I call setOnPageChangeListener() method

Tags: java, tabs, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, adapter

I have a mainactivity which contains a button on button click I am showing viewpager which has five screens. I want to show an actionbar onscreeen change of the viewpager but when I try to call the 
`mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener())`.

It is showing me null pointer exception.

Here is my code:

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener 
{

     private Button mAddButtonB,mPreviousB,mNextB,mhandle,mSave;
     SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
     ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
     actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
     context = this;
     mAddButtonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addnewB);
    mAddButtonB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mAddSearchV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.customviewpager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        }
    });

     mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new
             ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

     @Override public void onPageSelected(int position) {
     actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position); } });

     // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
     for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {  

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
     .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
     .setTabListener(this)); }


}
     public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And here is the Adapter class inside MainActivity

```
 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    PageZero p0;
    PageOne p1;
    PageTwo p2;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        /*
         * p0 = new PageZero(); p1 = new PageOne(); p2 = new PageTwo();
         */
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new PageZero();

        case 1:
            return new PageOne();

        case 2:
            return new PageTwo();

        case 3:
            return new PageThree();

        case 4:
            return new PageFour();
        }
        return null;
    }


     /*int index = mViewPager.getCurrentItem(); 
     SectionsPagerAdapter adapter= ((SectionsPagerAdapter)mViewPager.getAdapter()) ; 
     p0 =adapter.getFragment(index);*/


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 5 total pages.
        return 5;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Red";
        case 1:
            return "Green";
        case 2:
            return "Blue";
        case 3:
            return "White";
        case 4:
            return "Orange";

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Waiting for any answer.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because you haven't implemented all inherited abstract methods for onPageChangeListener